# is there an equivalent of EndpointInterceptorAdapter for the client?

Tags: spring-ws

Is there an equivalent of EndpointInterceptorAdapter for the client?

Because i need to intercept outgoing and incoming messages from the client and do some work with them.

EndpointInterceptorAdapter intercepts only endpoint messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found the answer.
You have to create a class that implements ClientInterceptor.

i.e.

```
package com.coral.project.interceptor;

public class WebServiceClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext)
        throws WebServiceClientException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext)
        throws WebServiceClientException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext)
        throws WebServiceClientException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

and define in spring-ws config file:

```
<bean id="crmClient" class="com.coral.project.clients.CrmClient">
    <property name="defaultUri" value="..."/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.coral.project.interceptor.WebServiceClientInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the SmartEndpointInterceptor

```
public class SmartEndpointInterceptorImpl implements
    SmartEndpointInterceptor 
{

    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)
        throws Exception 
    {
       SaajSoapMessage soapSaajMsg = (SaajSoapMessage)messageContext.getRequest();
       return true;
    }


    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)
        throws Exception {

       return true;
    }

  //I omitted two more methods
}
```

Comment: Interesting...     I will try this and report back :)

Comment: Well, this still intercepts only Endpoints, not clients. Any other ideas?